# Batch File to reformat list in text file

Tags: batch-file

Been researching a bit, but havent found an answer as of yet, so heres my first official post.

I have an app that outputs a LAN ID list to a text file. Unfortunately it has no formatting options. The list comes out on 1 LONG line like so:

```
user1 user2 user3 user4 user5 user6 user7
```

All on a single line, separated by a space. I need to put that into a single column, each on is own line, in a text file that another app will process:

```
userid1

userid2

userid3

userid4
```

I tried something like this, and variations, but to no avail:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (c:\lame_file.txt) do echo %%a >>c:\better_file.txt
```

Unfortunately, it maintains the original format. I've tried to few things to introduce a CR or LF, but none worked.

Any suggestion would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("c:\lame_file.txt") do (
   for %%b in (%%a) do >>"c:\better_file.txt" echo %%b
)
```

Comment: Thats pretty clever. Worked like a champ, thank you!

Comment: Ta.  It will break with characters like `;` and `=` but for alphanumerics it works fine.

Comment: It will also break if the length of the original line approaches 8191 bytes.